# Home Button in WKWebView, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, wkwebview

I have a `WkWebView` that load an url (example.com) with 2 button: back and home.

**Code for back button is**

```
func goBack(_ sender: Any) {
    if webView.canGoBack{
        webView.goBack()
    }
}
```

and works fine.

**Code for home button is**

```
func goHome(_ sender: Any) {
    let myURL = URL(string: "example.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}
```

but this works also if I'm already in example.com.

How can I make a check for reload example.com only if I'm not in example.com?

Comment: VKWebView or WKWebView?

Comment: @JD. WKWebView, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to check against the web view's current URL. The following would suffice:

```
if webView.url != myURL {
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}
```

Though I would recommend adding an appropriate scheme and path to your URL else this will return false. e.g. `URL(string: "https://example.com/")`.

Comment: myURL in viewDidLoad is a local variable so I’m not able to use in goHome method... (use of unresolved identifier ‘myURL’ error)

Comment: Perhaps define it at class level? As homeURL?

Comment: can you make an example? sorry but this is my first experience with swift and xcode...

Comment: I.E. Where you make your view controller class, under where you define `webView`, write `let homeURL = URL(string: "https://example.com/")!`.